# Graphically lay out scrollview (page view)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

Is there any way to easily lay out each page of a scroll view using horizontal scrolling and UIPageControl? Or if not is there a way I can make the views in storyboard, and then load each of these views in the relevant page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your views with "freeform" sizes and load the view from the storyboard using,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

customViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CutomOversizedViewController"];
```

Comment: And I can add these into a scrollview? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Sure, you can add them as a childViewController.  There is a WWDC 2011 video that covers this called "Implementing UIViewController Containment" here:https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/ (need Developer Account)  I just figured you would build your whole big view controller out with the scroll view and really not need to call it up from storyboard.  But the video will show you some good methods for containment and using parent and child view controllers (iOS 5 only I think)

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 added a class that is similar to what you need, called [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).

Searching the ref lib, there don't appear to be any samples published demoing the new class, but it should be relatively straightforward to test it out in your own implementation.

It takes an array of viewControllers, so in your case, it seems you could supply a list of repeating viewControllers that display scroll view, then manage a way to internally maintain a page index.